# Complex SQL Querying: Two queries within the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
ID  |     LABEL     |   SOME_VALUE
1           a              rand_1
2           a              NULL
3           b              rand_9
4           c              rand_3
5           c              rand_3
6           c              rand_3
7           d              NULL
8           d              rand_4
```

As you can see, ID is unique, label is not unique (can be 1 or more) and some_value is also not unique.

What I want to do is the following:

I want to get a unique list of LABELS, which exist in the database in more than one rows (min 2) and of which rows has SOME_VALUE not NULL.

So I would get:

```
ID  |     LABEL     |   SOME_VALUE
1           a            rand_1
2           a            NULL
7           d            NULL
8           d            rand_4
```

in return.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why have you excluded IDs 4, 5 and 6? Is it because you want more than one DISTINCT value for `SOME_VALUE` within the label group?

Comment: Hello! Because 4-5-6 have both label and some_value duplicated. I seek labels which have some_value so that I can make the same label in a different row without some_value use that value but first I wanted to see which ones are they.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions. First one does exactly as listed in results, eliminating rand_3 because even though it appears three times all the values are the same (I don't see distinct condition specified in question).

There must be a better way, but as they say *I can't brain today, I have the dumb* :-)

```
select * 
from tbl
inner join
(
  select label
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY Label
  HAVING count (distinct some_value) 
       + sum(distinct case when some_value is null then 1 else 0 end) > 1
) a
on tbl.label = a.label
```

Second one retrieves C also following the requirements (some_value being not null for at least one of some_value).

```
select * 
from tbl
inner join
(
  select label
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY Label
  HAVING count(*) > 1 and count(some_value) > 0
) a
on tbl.label = a.label
```

[And there is Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b187f/31).

Answer (score 2):

The HAVING parameter limits grouped items:

```
SELECT 
    Label
FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE NOT Some_Value IS NULL
GROUP BY Label
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: `where SOME_VALUE IS NOT NULL` before group by

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM yourTable t1
JOIN yourTable t2
ON t1.LABEL = t2.LABEL
AND t1.ID < t2.ID
WHERE t1.SOME_VALUE IS NOT NULL
OR t2.SOME_VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
SELECT test.*
FROM (
    SELECT label
    FROM test
    GROUP BY Label
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IFNULL(some_value, '~null~')) > 1
) AS tmp
INNER JOIN test
    ON tmp.label = test.label;
```

Comment: I was looking into same solution but give up because some_value might contain 'null' value resulting in miss where should have been a hit. I know that likelihood is extremely low though.

Comment: I am quite sure this handles NULLs correctly by converting them to the string 'null'. It works for all case that I have tried.

Comment: Except if you put 'null' (note apostrophes) in some_value in one row of label 'a' and NULL in another. `count (distinct` will see them as one. Again, this seems higly improbable.

Comment: Very true. Well spotted! Easily changed if 'null' is a valid entry in the table.